# high CPU usage after JavaScript setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cpu

I am having a PHP code which pulls out text from the database, and shows it in a div as links. I am refreshing that DIV every 3000 milliseconds, and the CPU usage is only a few percent higher upon the refresh itself. After 20-25 minutes of constant refreshes, when I click on one of the links, it takes about 20 seconds to open that page, and meanwhile the browser tab freezes up. More refreshes occur - more time it takes to open a link, as well as when more links are opened (if 10-15 links are opened, it gets as slow as 10-12 seconds to open next page). When browser is trying to open the link, 1 processor thread is fully loaded. Here is the code (simplified):

```
    <div id="map1"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="map1">

<?PHP


if (isset($_GET['m'])) {       

    $selectback = "SELECT parentid FROM MAP_LINK WHERE sysid = " . $_GET['m'];
    ................
    $rowb = ibase_fetch_row($query);        

    echo "<h6><a href=\"#\" id=\"back" . $rowb[0] . "\">BACK</a></h6><h4>
    <script>
       $('a#back" . $rowb[0] . "').click(function() {
           clearInterval(auto_refresh);    
               $(\"#map1\").load(\"test2.php?m=" . $rowb[0] . "\");

               auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
               $(\"#map1\").load(\"test2.php?m=" . $rowb[0] . "\");}, 3000);

               });
               </script>";





     $select = "SELECT sysid FROM MAP_LINK WHERE parentid = " . $_GET['m'];
     .........................................                   

    $x = 0;
    while ($x < $total_rows) {
        $x++;
        $row = ibase_fetch_row($query);
        echo "<br><a href=\"#\" id=\"" . $row[0] . "\">Link # " . $row[0] . "</a>
        <script>
                $('a#" . $row[0] . "').click(function() {
                 clearInterval(auto_refresh);    
               $(\"#map1\").load(\"test2.php?m=" . $row[0] . "\");

               auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
               $(\"#map1\").load(\"test2.php?m=" . $row[0] . "\");}, 3000);

               });
        </script>";

    }
} else {
    echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\"#map1\").load('test2.php?m=56');
auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
$(\"#map1\").load(\"test2.php?m=56\");}, 3000);
});</script>";
}
?>
```

This is about the same code I have. The database consists of 4 tables where data is pulled from. The first 6-7 clicks open next page momentarily with no delay, delays start after the 10th click and get bigger with each additional click or refresh.

My question is: How can I make it open immediately or at least faster? There is an error in code. It works, but it's using the CPU a lot and is getting slow enough to not being to navigate on page.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)  Don't use setInterval, use setTimeout that resubscribes the loop after the work is complete. That will insure the function can never reenter.

Comment: You're echoing intervals inside a while loop, who knows how many intervals you have running at the same time ?

Comment: You are triggering auto_refresh each time +1 if you press it.

Comment: will try to replace setInterval with setTimeout on Monday, will see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: setTimeout only refreshes the page once. I need it refreshed every x seconds until a link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Late for help but you could try chaining setTimeouts together, like this:

```
function refreshments() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Do stuff
        refreshments();
    }, 1000);
}

refreshments();
```